# php echo different content on different dates

Tags: php, date, if-statement, echo

I am using this date format to echo example: Thursday 8th August 2013

`$day = date("l jS F Y");`

I would like to echo different content on different dates

for example if it was Wednesday 25th December 2013 i can echo "merry christmas"

This is what i have tried, but this time format is (Y-m-d = 2013-25-12)
I have also tried just adding Wednesday 25th December 2013.

What date format should $day =  if im using  $day = date("l jS F Y");

```
<p><?php if( $day == '2013-25-12' ) 
echo 'action="Merry Christmas"';      
?></p>
```

Comment: You can perform comparisons using `date` with a single argument. For example, `date('Y') == 2013`, etc.

Comment: Ladies & Gentlemen, [**We have a WINNER!**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18115465/1415724)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get a similarly formatted date to compare to your $day:

```
<?php if( $day === date("l jS F Y", strtotime('2013-25-12'))) {
    echo 'Merry christmas!';
} ?>
```

Check out the php documentation on the date function. It includes the formatting specifications: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Referring to a PHP.net link is not an answer.

Comment: @HydraIO In some cases, it is considered an answer.

Comment: @woofmeow If something is blatant in the documentation that should be good enough. If one needs to figure something out it's a great place to look first...

Comment: @Tonithy Good answer, love it. However, you'll need to change your `php if` to `<?php if`. Cheers (*Peace*)

Comment: @Tonithy No problemo, cheers ;-) Might even want to add `else { echo "It's not Christmas"; }` should the OP decide to post a message ahead of time, if it's not Christmas.

Comment: @Fred I'm sure the OP left this thread long before we have; probably BECAUSE it isn't Christmas. Lol.

Comment: @Tonithy Probably! lol well I love projects like these. I'll code for fun when there's no work to be done, and today just happened to be one of those days.

Comment: @Tonithy Btw, did you notice my [**little note**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115442/php-echo-different-content-on-different-dates#comment26524383_18115442) ? ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35046/discussion-between-tonithy-and-fred)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little something I came up with, that you can add items to.

#### You're welcome to use it. (I love fun projects like these).

```
<?php
$date = date("m,d"); // month/day format
if($date == "08,07"){
     echo "It is today";
}

elseif($date == "02,14"){
     echo "It is valentine's Day";
}

elseif($date == "12,25"){
     echo "It is Christmas Day";
}
else{
     echo "It is not a holiday";
}
?>
```

---

**Footnote**: This was only an additional option, and not taking away from [**Tonithy's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18115465/1415724).

---

Answer (score 1):

Since $day returns the day of the week you can't use it to say merry Christmas, if you do it will only say "Merry Christmas" on Christmas if it is a Thursday. So write a separate switch function like this:

```
switch(date("m/d")){
  case '12/25':
    echo "merry christmas";
    break;
  //add other holidays
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i looking for exact dates and days because i am using $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and it echoes the inputted date, i need to if $day = ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [strtotime PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

One example of doing this is:

```
<?php
if (date('Y') == 2013 && date('d') == 25 && date('m') == 12)
{
  echo 'Merry christmas!';
}
?>
```

As another answer said, refer to the documentation ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ) for more examples

Comment: The OP didn't think of this, but maybe remove the check for the year if they are planning on dealing with holidays or other annually occurring events...

Answer (score 0):

I am on a bit of a [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) campaign at the moment, so here is my version:-

```
if((new \DateTime())->format('d m') === '25 12'){
    echo "Merry Christmas!";
}
```

It may be a bit neater in a Switch:Case block if you want to add a number of different holidays (as a little bonus I've added Easter):-

```
$easter = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp(easter_date())->format('d m');

switch((new \DateTime())->format('d m')){
    case '25 12';
        echo "Merry Christmas";
        break;
    case '14 02':
        echo "Happy Valentines Day!";
        break;
    case $easter:
        echo 'Happy Easter';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'No Holiday Today';
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/qGb57)